Ansible: A method to replace text in JSON file
I have task to modify value of a connector in a JSON file like this:
{
    "school": [
        {
            "class": "class1",
            "properties": {
                "pupil": {
                        "name": "Mya",
                        "age": "8"
                    }

                }
            },
        {
            "class": "class2",
            "properties": {
                "pupil": {
                        "name": "Mya",
                        "age": "8"
                        }
                }
        }
    ]
}

How to create an Ansible playbook to set new value only for pupil's name and age only in class1?
I expect the result as below.
{
    "school": [
        {
            "class": "class1",
            "properties": {
                "pupil": {
                        "name": "Jane",
                        "age": "9"
                    }

                }
            },
        {
            "class": "class2",
            "properties": {
                "pupil": {
                        "name": "Mya",
                        "age": "8"
                        }
                }
        }
    ]
}

Really appreciate your help please!

At a first glance one possible solution and a generic approach could be to use update_fact module – Update currently set facts.
A minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Read the file
    include_vars:
      file: file.json
      name: classes

  - name: Show the content
    debug:
      msg: "{{ classes }}"

  - name: Update the facts
    ansible.utils.update_fact:
      updates:
        - path: classes.school[0].properties.pupil.name
          value: Jane
        - path: classes.school[0].properties.pupil.age
          value: 9
    register: updated

  - name: Show the updated content
    debug:
      msg: "{{ updated.classes }}"

  - name: Update the file
    copy:
      dest: updated.file.json
      content: "{{ updated.classes | to_nice_json(indent=4) }}"

will result into the requested output of
TASK [Read the file] *****************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show the content] ***************
  msg:
    school:
    - class: class1
      properties:
        pupil:
          age: '8'
          name: Mya
    - class: class2
      properties:
        pupil:
          age: '8'
          name: Mya

TASK [Update the facts] **************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Show the updated content] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    school:
    - class: class1
      properties:
        pupil:
          age: 9
          name: Jane
    - class: class2
      properties:
        pupil:
          age: '8'
          name: Mya

TASK [Update the file] *****************
ok: [localhost]

and file content of
{
    "school": [
        {
            "class": "class1",
            "properties": {
                "pupil": {
                    "age": 9,
                    "name": "Jane"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "class2",
            "properties": {
                "pupil": {
                    "age": "8",
                    "name": "Mya"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Further Documentation

include_vars module – Load variables from files, dynamically within a task
to_json filter – Convert variable to JSON string
to_nice_json filter – Convert variable to "nicely formatted" JSON string
copy module – Copy files - Parameter: content

Similar Q&A

How to replace text of an XML element with Ansible?

